# Method for creating and traversing a BST while also getting its depth and width

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, design-patterns

This is a class for creating and traversing a BST while also getting its depth and width. I feel like this can be factored down into something more elegant and shorter I also feel like the overall design can be improved.

```js
class BinaryNode {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val
    this.left = null
    this.right = null
  }
}

class BinaryTree {
  constructor(traversal) {
      this.traversal = traversal
    }
    * inorder(node) {
      if (node === undefined) node = this.root;
      if (!node) {
        return;
      }
      if (node) {
        yield* this.inorder(node.left)
        yield node.val;
        yield* this.inorder(node.right)
      }
    }

  * preorder(node) {
    if (node === undefined) node = this.root;
    if (!node) {
      return;
    }
    if (node) {
      yield node.val;
      yield* this.preorder(node.left)
      yield* this.preorder(node.right)
    }
  }

  * postorder(node) {
    if (node === undefined) node = this.root;
    if (!node) {
      return;
    }
    if (node) {
      yield* this.preorder(node.left)
      yield* this.preorder(node.right)
      yield node.val
    }
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this[this.traversal]()
  }
  length() {
    const len = node => {
      if (!node) return 0;
      return 1 + len(node.left) + len(node.right);
    }
    return len(this.root)
  }

  height() {
    const hi = node => {
      if (!node) return 0;
      return 1 + Math.max(hi(node.left), hi(node.right))
    }
    return hi(this.root)
  }

  diameter() {
    let max = 0;
    dfs(this.root)
    return max

    function dfs(node) {
      if (!node) return -1;
      let left = dfs(node.left) + 1
      let right = dfs(node.right) + 1
      max = Math.max(max, left + right)
      return Math.max(left, right);
    }
  }
}


class BST extends BinaryTree {
  constructor(traverse) {
    super(traverse)
    this.string = '';
  }
  deseralize() {
    let data = this.string.split(" ")
    return this.deseralizer(data)
  }
  deseralizer(data) {
    let val = data.shift()
    if (!data.length || val === '#') {
      return null;
    } else {
      let node = new BinaryNode(val)
      node.left = this.deseralizer(data)
      node.right = this.deseralizer(data)
      return node;
    }
  }

  seralize(node) {
    this.root = node;
    this.string = ''
    this.seralizer(node)
    return this.string
  }
  seralizer(node) {

    if (!node) {
      this.string += '# '
    } else {

      this.string += node.val + ' '
      this.seralizer(node.left)
      this.seralizer(node.right)

    }
  }


}



var tree = new BST('preorder');

let root = {
  "val": 1,
  "right": {
    "val": 3,
    "right": {
      "val": 5,
      "right": null,
      "left": null
    },
    "left": {
      "val": 4,
      "right": null,
      "left": null
    }
  },
  "left": {
    "val": 2,
    "right": null,
    "left": null
  }
}
console.log('seralize: ', tree.seralize(root))
console.log('deseralize: ', tree.deseralize())
for (let i of tree) {
  console.log('preorder', i)

}
console.log('preorder', [...tree])
```